# TextBlock Wrap and scrollView

Tags: wpf, scrollview, textblock

The code below is working nice but the vertical `ScrollBar` is disabled even if large text inside of `TextBlock`. How can I enable it?

```
 <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModels:CommentsViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel >
            <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
            <Expander Header="Yo" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"  MaxHeight="250" 
                         Text="{Binding Article.Article.Content}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Expander>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I think the TextBox control auto handles scrolling if maybe you were to try that, any particular reason why you need the ScrollViewer?

Comment: Try setting VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visable".  And you should not set a MaxHeight of TextBlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found.

```
MaxHeight="250"
```

tag should be not in the `TextBlock`, but should be in the `Grid` to limit height. Then it will be working perfectly.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:CommentsViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <DockPanel >
        <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <Expander Header="Yo" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Grid MaxHeight="250"> 
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"   
                     Text="{Binding Article.Article.Content}"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Expander>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your just displaying text, to be certain it'll work use a `TextBox`:

```
        <Expander Header="Yo" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Grid IsReadOnly="True">
                <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"  MaxHeight="250" 
                     Text="{Binding Article.Article.Content}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Expander>
```